# alternate CSV row deletion

Tags: python

I have a csv file as follows:

```
gindex
1
1
2
2
3
3
7
7
```

I printed each element twice by mistake. How can I delete each repeated row and get the following results:

```
gindex
1
2
3
7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for fancy csv handling, if it is really just every second line you want to dismiss, do something like:

```
with open("csv") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
         if i % 2 == 0:
             print(line)
```

Comment: Oneliner! ;) [print(line) for i, line in enumerate(open("csv")) if not i%2] (don't do that, else a kitten dies)

Comment: very nice. this will avoid adding newlines `print(line,end='')`

Answer (score 1):

You could read the file into an array, skipping every other line, and then write it out (correctly this time!) overwriting the original file.  If the file is too big to store in memory, write the corrected version out as you read the original into a temp file, and then move/copy that to overwrite the original.